# How to Validate International Passport number in swift

Tags: ios, swift, validation

I am new in swift and I need to validate International passport. Is there is any way to validate it.

Comment: you wrote regular expression and it is the same for all programming languages. If you want to know how use it in swift - read, for example, [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/108/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-swift)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for Passport Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647728/regex-for-passport-number) and [How to use regex in swift.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches)

Answer (score 1):

try use **NSPredicate**:

```
  func isValidPassport(passportStr:String) -> Bool {        
    let passportRegEx = "^(?!^0+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$"

    let passportPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", passportRegEx)
    return passportPred.evaluate(with: passportStr)
  }
```

**Swift earlier than 3.0:**

```
func isValidPassport(passportStr:String) -> Bool {

    let passportRegEx = "^(?!^0+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$"

    let passportPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", passportRegEx)
    return passportPred.evaluate(with: passportStr)
}
```

**Swift earlier than 1.2:**

```
class func isValidPassport(passportStr:String) -> Bool {

    let passportRegEx = "^(?!^0+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$"

    if let passportPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", passportRegEx) {
        return passportPred.evaluateWithObject(passportStr)
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You can check like below

```
extension String {

    func isValidPassport() -> Bool {
        let PASSPORT_REG_EX = "^(?!^0+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$"
        let passport = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", PASSPORT_REG_EX)

        if (self.count >= 6) {
            return passport.evaluate(with: self)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Take a `String Extension` and reuse rest of your App

```
    let passport = "AS345501"
    passport.isValidPassport()
```

Note: [How to validate a passport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673947/how-to-validate-a-passport/1674006)

> UK passport numbers consist of 9 digits but used to consist of 6
>   digits and a letter.

Happy coding...